# SQL Server: proper use of Select with calendar table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, stored-procedures, calendar

I have created a calendar table that contains all the calendar dates of a year, incl. the corresponding quarter / week / month / day etc. information.

The following Select gives me all Fridays in December. 
What would be the best way here to get only the second out of these ?

```
SELECT     *
FROM       Calendar
WHERE      (yearCal = '2014') AND (monthCal = '12') AND (weekDayCal = '6')
```

Many thanks in advance, Mike.

Comment: I recommend adding the various [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) values of the date (ISO week-year, ISO week of year, ISO day of week, etc), especially as your day-of-week does _not_ match the ISO numbers (your Monday is `'2'`, the ISO Monday is `'1'`).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - Different businesses have different week definitions.

Comment: @MatBailie - which is _exactly_ why I recommend adding the ISO numbers - so common ground can be stated if necessary.  The other good thing about the ISO definitions is that they're immune to things like changing server regions (or even just session region changes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `day_of_month` type of field, the second Friday must be day 8 to 14.

```
SELECT     *
FROM       Calendar
WHERE      (yearCal    = 2014)
       AND (monthCal   = 12)
       AND (weekDayCal = 6)
       AND (dayInMonth BETWEEN 8 AND 14)
```

You could use a `Week of month` field, but this can get complex depending on what you define as a week.  Normally it would by Monday-Sunday or similar, meaning that `week1` of `month12` ***may*** only be 2 days long, and not include a Friday.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, I have and this works perfect ! Will accept as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a recurring requirement, then you should add a column `weekInMonthCal` and include it in the constraint clause.

It is possible to count in SQL but, as this involves aggregation in the result set, it is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` function to order your results (replace the column `DateColumn` with your column which stores dates. You can then get the second record.

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT     Col1, Col2, Col3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateColumn) RowNumber
FROM       Calendar
WHERE      (yearCal = '2014') AND (monthCal = '12') AND (weekDayCal = '6'))

SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM CTE
WHERE RowNumber = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This would give you the second friday of a given month

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM
(SELECT     top 2 *
FROM       Calendar
WHERE      (yearCal = '2014') AND (monthCal = '12') AND (weekDayCal = '6')
order by dateCal asc) a
order by dateCal desc
```